# Update Material slider UI when another slider is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, material-design

I'm in trouble with my inputs. Both of the inputs are connected. When you click on the first one, the second inputs will move but the css will not update.

```js
var $ra1 = $('#range1');
var $ra2 = $('#range2');

$ra1.on('input', function() {
    $ra2.val(this.max - this.value);
});
$ra2.on('input', function() {
    $ra1.val(this.max - this.value);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Range 1
<input type="range" min="0" max="400" value="0" class="mdl-slider mdl-js-slider " id="range1">

Range 2
<input type="range" min="0" max="400" value="400" class="mdl-slider mdl-js-slider" id="range2">
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
I found a workaround for IE11

```js
var $ra1 = $('#range1');
var $ra2 = $('#range2');
if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' ||  !!(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/) || navigator.userAgent.match(/rv:11/)) || (typeof $.browser !== "undefined" && $.browser.msie == 1)){
    $ra1.change(function(){
        $ra2.get(0).MaterialSlider.change(this.max - this.value);
    });
    $ra2.change(function(){
        $ra1.get(0).MaterialSlider.change(this.max - this.value);
    });
 }else{
    $ra1.on('input', function() {
        $ra2.get(0).MaterialSlider.change(this.max - this.value);
    });
    $ra2.on('input', function() {
        $ra1.get(0).MaterialSlider.change(this.max - this.value);
    });
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Range 1
<input type="range" min="0" max="400" value="0" class="mdl-slider mdl-js-slider " id="range1"> 
Range 2
<input type="range" min="0" max="400" value="400" class="mdl-slider mdl-js-slider" id="range2">
```

Comment: It's the Material Design Lite framework

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this to work you need to set the value through the Material library, not jQuery, in order for it to update the UI. To do that, use the `change` function on the `MaterialSlider` property of the DOM element, like this:

```js
var $ra1 = $('#range1');
var $ra2 = $('#range2');

$ra1.on('input', function() {
  $ra2.get(0).MaterialSlider.change(this.max - this.value);
});

$ra2.on('input', function() {
  $ra1.get(0).MaterialSlider.change(this.max - this.value);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Range 1
<input type="range" min="0" max="400" value="0" class="mdl-slider mdl-js-slider " id="range1"> Range 2
<input type="range" min="0" max="400" value="400" class="mdl-slider mdl-js-slider" id="range2">
```

Comment: It looks like it's not supported on IE11

Comment: That's unfortunate. If you need IE11 support I'd suggest raising a note with the Materialize devs, or using a different library.